Issue with Laravel application deployment on Heroku
I am new to Heroku and trying to deploy my first Laravel application. However, when I attempt to build the application via a push from Git, I encounter the following error:

app[web.1]: Composer could not detect the root package
(laravel/laravel) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See
https://getcomposer.org/root-version

In my composer.json file, I have the following line:
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
"keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
  "php": "^8.1",
  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
  "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.6.8",
  "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
  "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
  "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
  "league/flysystem-ftp": "^3.0",
  "league/flysystem-sftp-v3": "^3.23",
  "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~3.0",
  "propa/tcpdi": "^1.3",
  "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.6",
  "tightenco/ziggy": "^1.0"
}

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue? My application works fine locally with Laravel.

10.10 is not available for laravel framework. Try adding 10.3

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does everything work properly on your own machine?

As someone else has mentioned, ^10.10 is not a valid version constraint. The latest version of Laravel 10.x is 10.3.3. Also, the message you‘ve posted isn’t a blocking error; it’s just a Composer notice. So if you application is not deploying then I imagine you’re getting a different error after that. Please post that error instead.
